# Javascript function to double click a button / click twice

Tags: javascript, jsf, file-upload

i have done a quick search but can not find a solution,

i am new to js so sorry if this is a daft simple question,

but is it possible to have some js that when a user clicks a single click on a button, the javascript presses the button twice

this is the button i wish the js to work on :

```
   <p:fileUpload widgetVar="upload" id="upload" fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.handleFileUpload}"
                                  mode="advanced" 
                                  multiple="false" 
                                  update="messages Nav upload fileDirectoryViewer"
                                  label="Select File"
                                  sizeLimit="30720000"  
                                  allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|doc|txt|pdf|html)$/"
                                  auto="true"
                                  disabled="#{fileUploadController.uploadComplete}"
                                  />
```

here is the source code for that page :

```
            <!--&lt;p:growl id=&quot;messages&quot; showSummary=&quot;true&quot; showDetail=&quot;true&quot; /&gt; --><div id="j_idt8:upload" class="ui-fileupload ui-widget"><div class="fileupload-buttonbar ui-widget-header ui-corner-top"><label class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left fileinput-button"><span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c ui-icon-plusthick"></span><span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Select File</span><input type="file" id="j_idt8:upload_input" name="j_idt8:upload_input" /></label></div><div class="fileupload-content ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom"><table class="files"></table></div></div><script id="j_idt8:upload_s" type="text/javascript">$(function(){PrimeFaces.cw('FileUpload','upload',{id:'j_idt8:upload',mode:'advanced',autoUpload:true,dnd:true,update:'j_idt8:messages j_idt8:Nav j_idt8:upload j_idt8:fileDirectoryViewer',process:'@none',maxFileSize:30720000,acceptFileTypes:/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|doc|txt|pdf|html)$/},'fileupload');});</script>
```

Thanks guys :)

Comment: Why would you need to do something like that?

Comment: clicks twice, or double-clicks? The browser won't let you trigger default action for the latter (not that there is one, though)

Comment: clicks twice, and to trigger the button it only works on once a user clicks twice, and i want this to happen on a single click

Comment: It looks like you're using Java Server Faces; the default browser upload control does not require a double-click, so JSF must be adding some code to require that. I'd solve this through JSF (or by using something other than JSF) instead.

Comment: The question is what Pointy asked, why would you want to do a double click, if its about executing the action twice, you can simply call it accordingly in you controller.